# How to create a delay in asm for the MOS 6502

Tags: assembly, delay, 6502

I'm new to ASM and I trying to workout how to create a delay for the following code:

```
org $1000

loop: inc $d021
    jmp loop
```

Comment: Yeah it is, it is just a change foreground program

Comment: You mean the background?

Comment: If by "delay" you mean waiting for the next scanline, then add an inner loop that waits for `$d012` to change.

Comment: No i mean by waiting for a second then changing color (sorry to confuse)

Comment: Then wait for `$d012` to change 320*50 times, or use a raster interrupt where you count frames.

Comment: Note: some compilers will throw errors when colons are used with labels. If you're getting 'invalid operand, label or variable "...". Try removing the colon after the label. So loop: will change to loop. CBM Studio compiler will give this error for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comments are clear enough i guess.

Code sample for changing color each frame (1/50 of a second)

```
        sei       ; enable interrupts

loop1:  lda #$fb  ; wait for vertical retrace
loop2:  cmp $d012 ; until it reaches 251th raster line ($fb)
        bne loop2 ; which is out of the inner screen area

        inc $d021 ; increase background color

        lda $d012 ; make sure we reached
loop3:  cmp $d012 ; the next raster line so next time we
        beq loop3 ; should catch the same line next frame

        jmp loop1 ; jump to main loop
```

Code sample for changing color each second

```
counter = $fa ; a zeropage address to be used as a counter

        lda #$00    ; reset
        sta counter ; counter

        sei       ; enable interrupts

loop1:  lda #$fb  ; wait for vertical retrace
loop2:  cmp $d012 ; until it reaches 251th raster line ($fb)
        bne loop2 ; which is out of the inner screen area

        inc counter ; increase frame counter
        lda counter ; check if counter
        cmp #$32    ; reached 50
        bne out     ; if not, pass the color changing routine

        lda #$00    ; reset
        sta counter ; counter

        inc $d021 ; increase background color
out:
        lda $d012 ; make sure we reached
loop3:  cmp $d012 ; the next raster line so next time we
        beq loop3 ; should catch the same line next frame

        jmp loop1 ; jump to main loop
```

Comment: You can use Y instead of zero page and A. And instead of incrementing the counter, decrement it, so you can implicitly BNE on Y. Shorter, faster, more idiomatic. See my edit request.

Comment: Since i love to code 256 bytes intros, i use many more tricks like self modifying code, illegal opcodes, shared register values etc. But this code sample is specially written for someone who said "I'm new to ASM". So, this is neither size nor cycle optimized source code. This is a code sample for beginners and i believe reversed loops may confuse them.

Comment: I'd argue using zero-page makes is more complicated than using the Y register, regardless of how you loop (reverse or forward), specially if A is used for 2 purposes. My suggestion was not to reduce code size or the number of cycles (that's a side effect) but rather to increase readability. Maybe using the Y register forward, with an explicit CPY, would have made an even nicer beginner solution.

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
loop: ldx $d021
      inx
      stx $d021
      cpx #100
      bne loop
```

Comment: This doesn't change $d021 once per second, it changes it once every 15 cycles until its' value is #100 (which is entirely variable since we don't know what is in $d021 to start with).

Comment: On the very beginning user3049038 wrote only about loop so I wrote a loop for him. 
There were nothing more info about that $d021 is HW register - so my answer is correct.

Comment: $D020/01 are very well known adresses for us dinosaurs. Especially in conjunction with a 6502/10. ;)

Comment: Maybe for C64 dinos. I have Atari 800xl so I don't know this register :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  This should change the background, wait 4 seconds, then change it again.  Repeat forever.

Note, you can change the number of seconds to anything from 0 to 255.

This is for `NTSC` machines but you can change the `60` to `50` for `PAL`.

```
main:
    inc $D021

    ldx #4          //  Wait 4 seconds
loop1:
    ldy #60
loop2:

waitvb:
    bit $D011
    bpl waitvb
waitvb2:
    bit $D011
    bmi waitvb2

    dey
    bne loop2
    dex
    bne loop1

    jmp main
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can ensure that the code doesn't cross a page boundary, a useful approach is to have a pair of bytes somewhere in RAM which will hold a computed jump address, and use an indirect jump into something like the following:

```
TableStart:
    cmp #$C9
    cmp #$C9
    cmp #$C9
    cmp #$C9
    cmp #$C9
    ...
TableEnd:
    nop
```

If the jump vector points to tableEnd, code will reach the instruction
after the NOP after seven cycles.  If it points one byte earlier, eight
cycles.  Two bytes earlier, nine cycles, etc.  Setting up the jump vector
may take a little while, but the delay itself will be smoothly adjustable
from seven cycles to any higher value in single-cycle increments.  Flags
will be trashed, but no registers will be affected.